# AngularJS Form Validation ($invalid, $error, etc.)

Tags: angularjs, validation

For the following code:

```
userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required> 
...
myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}
myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}
```

Both `$valid` and `$error` will be `false` if the user touched the input and left it empty.

My question is:

1. How does angularjs define `$valid` and `$error`? For example, `$touched` has two states (touched or untouched). but what does it mean by "valid" or "invalid"?
2. Can I customize or redefine them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$valid` simply return a boolean value depending on input is valid or not. But `$error` provide detail information about the errors. For eg, if you couple of validations setup for a form and all of them are invalid, then the error will show the details description of all the errors.

[Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXV5ID84A3MA)